# How to run multiple jars with an argument in a script

Tags: bash, jar

I have couple of .jar files which are taking one common input(which is a folder). It's basically a converter. I want to write a script that can do all of them at once.

```
java -jar myjava1.jar myfoldername
java -jar myjava2.jar myfoldername
java -jar myjava3.jar type3 myfoldername
```

I checked other topics but didn't find something that can solve my issue. My apologies if similar topic was exist before. ps: running os is windows.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the directory structure of the working directory. If your jar files are all at the same level, you can do

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && { 
        echo "Usage: $0 jar-argument";
        exit 1
}

for J in *.jar;do
    java -jar "$J" "$1"
done
```

If you have your jar files in different nested levels, you can use **find**

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && { 
        echo "Usage: $0 jar-argument"
        exit 1 
}

find . -name "*.jar" -exec java -jar "{}" "$1" \;
```

Comment: Don't use `ls` to `find` files.

Comment: Thank you @ceving, I edited my code after your suggestion